# The name 'FileUtil' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am encountering the error- "The name 'FileUtil' does not exist in the current context" only when i am building my unity app for android but it runs fine without any errors when i run it in the editor. This line basically deletes a folder

I have tried adding using System.IO; but it still isn't working. Also it works if I remove the line.

```
public void Delete()
{
    P = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.transform;
    FileUtil.DeleteFileOrDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/ARPortal/"  + P.parent.gameObject.name);
    P.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    P.parent.GetChild(4).transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    counter = 0;
}
```

Is there any workaround or alternate to delete a folder.[Snippet ofthe error i am encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfKJ4.png)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FileUtil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FileUtil.html) is part of the `UnityEditor` namespace. It does not exist in a build but only within the Unity Editor itself.

=> **You can not use anything from it in a built App.**

---

Usually you only use it for editor scripts (things that shall only happen in Unity e.g. for having fancy Inspectors etc).

In order to exclude such code parts from a build there are basically two ways:

1. Make sure all editor script are placed in folders named `Editor`. Those are automatically excluded from the build process.
2. If you only want to exclude certain code blocks of the build (everything using `UnityEditor` you can use the [if pre-processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) with `UNITY_EDITOR`

   ```
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       using UnityEditor;
   #endif

   ...

   #if UNITY_EDITOR
       // some code using the UnityEditor namespace
   #endif
   ```

---

For deleting a folder on runtime you could use e.g. [`Directory.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete)

For a file you can use [`File.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete)

In both cases you should never directly concatenate path strings but rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

```
using System.IO;

...

var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "ARPortal", P.parent.gameObject.name);

//if it is an empty folder use
Directory.Delete(path);

//if it is a folder with content use
Directory.Delete(path, true);

//if it is a file use
File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: Thank you, Directory.delete() worked although i had to use the recurvsive delete since the folder wasnt empty. so i used-     Directory.delete("path name",true)